В батнике при соединении строк обрывается вторая строка
Ребят, помогите, а? Вот такой код:
"C:\prosto fotka s kakim-to "^
"imenem.png" & pause

выполняется на раз, нужная фотка открывается в улет, все идеально. Но уже вот такой код:
"C:\prosto fotka s kakim-t"^
"o imenem.png" & pause

не выполняется с такой формулировкой:

C:\Users\User>"C:\prosto fotka s kakim-t""o imenem.png" & pause
""C:\prosto fotka s kakim-t""o" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Я понимаю, что не выполняется он потому, что обрубается вторая часть имени фотки, только как это исправить, я ума не приложу. И так пробовал, и так, а оно никак. И Гугл весь излазил, - тщетно.

Ну cmd - это адовое легаси. Если хочется оставаться внутри экосистемы винды - присмотрись к powershell. На нём сейчас пишут больше людей.

Рабочий код есть, но он дурацкий:
"C:\prosto fotka s kakim-t"^
o" imenem.png" & pause

Давно сталкиваюсь с такими вот проблемами старого командного процессора, но приходится с этим жить: на некоторых  приборах только так получается.
И, да, благородный дон Румата :) прав - присмотритесь к Powershell

@Vikior Tomilov , надо же! Кто бы мог подумать! Казалось бы, древняя наироднейшая программа самой винды, все глюки уже 100 лет как должны были быть выловлены. Ан нет. А мне тоже удалось как бы решение проблемы в данном случае. Я подумал; если cmd обрубает строку по этому пробелу, то что, если этот пробел взять и заэкранировать? Написал код так; "C:\prosto fotka s kakim-t"^
"o^ imenem.png^" & pause (перенос строки после ^) и о, чудо, код сработал! Вариант, предложенный благородным доном, мне б и в голову не пришел. Он говорит о том, что интерпретатор воспринимает расположенное между первой и

второй кавычками как текст. И что, конечно? здесь так, там так. Толк от этих находок только в том, что теперь знаю о глюках в кмд. А так. Для каждого же случая не наподбираешься варианта, перевариваемого строкой. С Powershell... Я, конечно, буду иметь его ввиду, но для меня переход на новый ЯА довольно-таки заморочное мероприятие. Конечно, не скажу, что неподъемное, но довольно-таки трудоемкое. Всем спасибо за ответы!
